# ffmpeg static builds from john requires libraries?

Tags: 18.04, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run ffmpeg with ubuntu 18.04. I downloaded latest git build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

But when I try to run any ffmpeg command, it complains about a lot of missing libraries like

```
libfdk-aac.so.1
libva.so.2
libass.so.9
libSDL2-2.0.so.0
```

Just to name a few...isn't the point of a static build to not require anything else to run? Or am I doing something wrong?

I feel like there are endless libraries I have to install to make it work. Is there a way to just install everything it needs?

And I believe most libraries in the repos would be super old right?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the downloaded version? How/where did you install it? What does `type -a ffmpeg` say?

Comment: John's ffmpeg builds don't use libfdk-aac, so the particular ffmpeg you are executing is from elsewhere.

Comment: @llogan what do you mean he doesn't use libfdk-aac? How he does AAC then?

Comment: The native FFmpeg AAC encoder is used (`-c:a aac`). libfdk-aac is non-free (at least with GPL) and therefore non-redistributable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are picking up *another* version of FFmpeg as John Van Sickle's FFmpeg does not show these error messages.

Try installing as follows:

```
mkdir ~/bin && cd ~/bin
wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
tar xvf ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz --no-anchored 'ffmpeg' --strip 1
source ~/.profile
```

And this should set you up with John's static FFmpeg for a *local* user! I tested this on my 18.04 system and it worked very well. Only remaining task would be to consider removing the archive remaining, if you have no further use for it:

```
rm ~/bin/ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
```

And that should do it...

**References:**

- [Frequently Asked Questions](http://ps://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/): The FAQs for John Van Sickle's FFmpeg static builds with a few more installation options. I note that he does not use the `~/bin` approach that I have described here.

Comment: Weird, but I did a apt purge ffmpeg* and apt remove ffmpeg*, then did what you said and now it works! Thanks